# Cut out parts of Three.js scene using a black and white image

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have a Three.js scene and a black and white image. I would like to use the image as a sort of stencil and cut out the parts of the scene that fall into the white areas and show the parts that fall into the black areas. I've tried (unsuccessfully) to do this using WebGL features such as stencils and blending and am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_masking.html

Comment: @WestLangley This is not the desired effect- that example is using the actual objects in the Three.js world as masks for images. I want to mask out parts of my objects, using a black and white image, depending on the color at a particular pixel. Are you saying that this is possible using EffectComposer?

Comment: It should be possible using `EffectComposer`, but granted, you will have to understand `MaskPass` and `EffectComposer` line-by-line to do it, and it may take considerable effort. If you are experienced, consider it a challenge. :)